# Datatype for string field and birthdate in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL and I want to create a table in with firstname, lastname and birthdate fields.

What is the appropriate data type for these three fields?

Thanks.

Comment: Which types do you think would be good, and why? Even questions like this can actually be somewhat interesting (and more useful) if some initial work/hypothesis/testing has been performed and annotated in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
first name : varchar(50)
Last name : varchar(50)
birthdate : date
```

These are the datatype you need

Comment: @pst this is just an example, you can increase the varchar(xx) value, but don't make it too long and slow down your queries